# How to get sub-root certificates in the certificate?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I'm reading the certificate file with the following methods :

```
 File certFile = new File("E:/mycert.cer");
 InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(certFile);
 CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
 X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(stream);
```

how to get the root certificate of the certificate with java programming.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get sub-root certificates in the certificate?

You can't. They aren't in the certificate. You need to:

1. Have a stream that contains a certificate *chain,* not just a single certificate, and
2. Call [`generateCertificates()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificates%28java.io.InputStream%29) instead of `generateCertificate(),` so as to get a `Collection<? extends Certificate>`, or
3. Call [`generateCertPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertPath%28java.io.InputStream%29) so as to get a `CertPath,` which contains an ordered `List` of `Certificate`, from which you can get the root, the leaf, and the intermediates.